# How to read YAML configuration sections

Tags: java, yaml

I'm creating a Yaml configuration reader. I'm having some problems to get the values
from sections. I have already created a way to read not sectioned-keys but when a section like

```
Test:
  Yes:
    True: a
    False: b
  No:
    True:
      Default: c
    False: d
```

is on the yml file, I want to add the path of the values to a HashMap. In the case above,
the path in the HashMap would be

```
Test.Yes.True = a
Test.Yes.False = b
Test.No.True.Default = c
Test.No.False = d
```

notice that Yes and No are sections inside Test. True and False values are inside the section Yes that is in Test etc.
I have no idea how read like the block above.

Comment: Can you show what you did for the "not sectioned-keys"?  That will help us see more clearly what you're trying to do, and then we can give you more relevant answers for getting values from sections.

Comment: Is there anything difficult about creating keys for your hashmap based on looking at the tabs at successive depths in the input file?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should show what you have tried and where you failed. That helps us to provide **very specific answer to your question.**

For now, Try converting yaml to corresponding Java POJO. You can do this directly or in steps. You can do it by yourself or can use online converters.

1. Firstly, you can convert from yaml file to Json. https://www.json2yaml.com/
2. then with the json, you can create Java POJO's.  http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ OR http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

The converted json to java POJO will automatically create proper mapping format for you and then you can easily use them.

for your most nested "Default" value case, you can take HashMap with name `"HashMap<String, String> trueHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>()"` if you wish, otherwise a new POJO with "True.java" will also work".

```
public class True
{
    private String false;
    private String true;
    // getters setters
}
```

And then, You need to do some research to map them and pick the configuration.
*NOTE:
You can do it by multiple online converters. I have provided only the popular ones.*